# What is the conventional definition of $d(x,y)^{p}$?

Tags: geometry, probability-theory, definition, optimal-transport, wasserstein

In Optimal transportation, and more precisely in
"[Optimal Transport: Old and New](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)" (Definition. 6.1, on page 106 - actually on page 111 out of 998, in this link), the Wasserstein distance $W_p$ is defined through the so-called "cost function", $c(x,y)=d(x,y)^{p}$, where $p\in [1,\infty)$:

$W_{p}(\mu,\nu) = \Bigg( \inf_{\pi \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)} \int_{X} d(x,y)^{p} d\pi(x,y) \Bigg) ^{\frac{1}{p}}$

I cannot find a clear definition of the object $d(x,y)^{p}$, that should be, *likely*, an Euclidean distance (maybe, something like $d(x,y)^{p}=\left|x-y\right|^{p}$ ?). Therefore, what is the conventional definition of $d(x,y)^{p}$?

Comment: Isn't it just the $p$-th power of $d(x,y)$ where $d$ is any metric?

Comment: So, you mean the power of the Euclidean distance, $d(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|$ ?

Comment: The definition starts with *"Let $(X,d)$ be a Polish metric space ..."*. ("Polish spaces" are described under "Conventions" (pg 10) as "complete, separable metric spaces, equipped with their Borel $\sigma$-algebra".) So, evidently, $d$ is whatever metric has been defined on the space; there doesn't seem to be any requirement for the metric to be Euclidean. That $d(x,y)^p$ is merely the $p$-th power of the metric is consistent with the appearance of enclosing $1/p$-th power to *normalize* the computed value.

Comment: I think it starts to be clearer...If the Polish metric space $X$ is an Euclidean space, i.e. $X=\mathbb{R}$, then the general metric $d(x,y)$ becomes an Euclidean distance among $x$ and $y$, i.e. $d(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|$. It should then hold also for its $p-$th power, i.e. $d(x,y)^{p}=\left|x-y\right|^{p}$.  For example, in the same previous reference, on page 277 (actually, page 283 out of 998), we can read: "If $\mathcal{M} = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the Euclidean space, then $d(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|$"... Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Also, Yes, as you wrote, $d(x,y)$ are metrics on a Polish space $X$. Then, if $X=\mathbb{R}$ we have an Euclidean distance  $d(x,y)=\left|x-y\right|$... I found a summary table at the end of that reference, at the very end of the book, i.e. on pages 991 and 992 (the table is named as "Some notable cost functions")..